# Android: ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT initial folder /DCIM or /Documents rather than Download

Tags: android, documents-provider

since SDK33 my APP cannot access folders such as DCIM or Documents anymore after requesting permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE due to access not granted - as it was necessary while using older SDKs. A possible workaround was given in the subsequent cited Reddit thread by using the SAF instead:

Accessing Shared Storage on SDK 33, Android >= 11 from native API : r/androiddev (reddit.com)

I can confirm that after the user interacted with the filesystem via SAF by storing a file inside a particular folder later on this particular folder remains  available to store other files an internal process of the app without further user interaction. This would solve my issue if I could let the user directly see a folder like DCIM or Documents instead of Downloads on their first interaction with the SAF right after installing this app. However so far I’ve researched other threads here

Pick a directory/file using Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT (Storage Access Framework)
[Pick a directory/file using Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT (Storage Access Framework)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22548994/pick-a-directory-file-using-intent-action-create-document-storage-access-framew)

and there

Cannot set the initial location of documents navigator using Storage Access Framework (SAF)
[Cannot set the initial location of documents navigator using Storage Access Framework (SAF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50460638/cannot-set-the-initial-location-of-documents-navigator-using-storage-access-fram)

those threads seem to suggest this is not possible. I also tried the following code which is invoked by UI (e.g.in button1onclick) however it also points always into the download folder no matter what is provided as initial uri after installing the app for the first time:

```
 String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()   + "/" + "DCIM" + "/";
Uri loc_pickerInitialUri = Uri.parse(path);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("application/jpg");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "TestImage.jpg");
intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, loc_pickerInitialUri);
startActivityForResult( intent, 0);
```

I would really appreciate a hint on how I can make the document provider called by the code above is initially pointing to DCIM or Documents instead of Downloads to save a file after the app was installed on a (new) phone.

Edit: I rewrote my post to match recommendations given in comments below.

Edit1: Rewrote my post again to match results of the meanwhile gained knowledge – my initial issue an SDK33-compiled app’s request for permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE yields access not granted can easily be solved by just removing that request. This works for Android 11 ..13 for accessing the DCIM folder for creating and opening files and for creating subdirectories – hope this is correct so far and might also helps those who come to here due to the mentioned Reddit link above.

Comment: `since SDK33 my APP cannot access folders such as DCIM or Documents anymore that where available previously` That is not true to begin with. But what is it that you wanna do? Create your own files or read them of others? (Edit your post with this info please).

Comment: For the rest you put a wrong type of initial ari. In principle you should put an uri you also obtained with that action.

Comment: Hi and thanks for commenting – I rewrote my post and I think it’s true for the case if the app was installed on a (new) phone without prior user interaction with the SAF inside that app. The first user interaction with the SAF would yield an URI which then can be used to point the user into that folder for subsequent SAF interactions. So what I need is something for the first ever user interaction with the SAF after installing the App.

Answer (score 1):

Without SAF: On an Android 13 device your app can create files in all public directories on external storage without needing any permission.

So also in DCIM and Documents.

Comment: Hi and thanks for commenting – that would be great but how can this be done after the App was just installed on a (new) phone and without any prior user-interaction with the SAF inside that APP ?

Comment: You dont need SAF for that. Just create the files in the old way.

Comment: Thanks for commenting – unfortunately not if the folder is forwarded to unmanaged c/c++ code such a tiff library to write a tiff –                                                             
the first step inside that library is to my knowledge:                                                         fd = open(name, m, 0666); // fcntl.h  in http://www.libtiff.org/ -> crash

Comment: That statement does tell nothing without showing value for name to begin with.

Comment: OK I checked the content for SDK33 – the char* name contains:  /storage/emulated/o/DCIM/Test.tiff   -- If I enable a breakpoint for this line the app interestingly does without crash (without prior permission request). Subsequent attempts to save Test1.tiff, Test2tiff etc. also succeed. Then I tried another phone that hasn’t seen the app yet – does also work. So can’t reproduce the crash and don’t know why it liked to crash before. Looks like the much simpler solution is to stick with the given process but without requesting a permission.

Answer (score 1):

With SAF ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT: Try to manupilate initial uri like i did here:

[Android 11 ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE: set initial URI to the Documents folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67552027/android-11-action-open-document-tree-set-initial-uri-to-the-documents-folder/67554693#67554693)

Comment: Thanks for commenting – this actually saved my day. To retrieve the permitted folder I did then the following in onActivityResult:
                        Uri storagemanger_ret_uri = data.getData();
                        String[] rawtreepathreturned = storagemanger_ret_uri.getPath().split(":");
                        if(rawtreepathreturned[0].contains("primary")) {
                            PermittedPath = "/storage/emulated/0/" + rawtreepathreturned[1];
                        } else PermittedPath = null;

Comment: Sorry but that is nonsense. If you use ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT then use the obtained uri. Dont mess around with it to obtain a file system path. Use the uri. I would fire you if you worked for me ;-).

Comment: Before firing me be so kind to tell how to deal with uri in c/c++ code such as if I would like to save tiff file e.g.: c++ code:  fd = open(name, m, 0666); // fcntl.h in libtiff.org

Comment: All that i dont know. But then dont use SAF at all. Look at my other answer for Android 13+;

Comment: Thanks a lot - to accommodate to gained knowledge I rewrote my initial post a second time.